# Postfix 550 5.1.1 <usr@domain.tld>: Recipient address rejected: User unknown in relay recipient table;

Tags: email, postfix, dovecot

I want to have postfix relaying mail to my dovecot, which is running on the same host. My users are defined in dovecot's passwd file under /etc/dovecot/users like this:

```
usr@domain.tld:{PLAIN}pw.:10000:10000::/srv/mail/domain/user::
```

When mails are recieved for a user with no system user, I get the following error:

```
NOQUEUE: reject: RCPT from sender[ip]: 550 5.1.1 <usr@domain.tld>: Recipient address rejected: User unknown in relay recipient table;
```

I configured postfix to relay my mails as follows:

```
mydestination = $myhostname, localhost
relay_domains = btree:/etc/postfix/relay_domains
transport_maps = btree:/etc/postfix/transport, $relay_domains
address_verify_map = btree:$data_directory/verify_cache
local_recipient_maps = 
smtpd_recipient_restrictions = permit_mynetworks, reject_unauth_destination, reject_unknown_recipient_domain, reject_unverified_recipient
```

The contents of relay_domains and transport are:

```
domain.tld lmtp:[127.0.0.1]
```

Here is what I tried already:

1. Remove my domains from mydestinations
2. Set local_recipient_maps to $relay_domains
3. Set local_recipient_maps null
4. Remove relay_domains from parent_domain_matches_subdomains

I don't really understand where postfix has its recipient table. From my understanding it shouldn't use this with my configuration. From what I read, with smtpd_recipient_restrictions, postfix should send a probe-mail to dovecot to check whether an address exists or not and should forward it if it is.

I highly appreciate any help solving this.

You find my complete postconf here: https://pastebin.com/jGeUmCxg

Answer (score 0):

This was solved by reinstalling postfix with the packetmanager. Apparently some change I was not aware of was made.

Comment: What version was the change made in?